# How to use "canvas.tag_bind" properly?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Hi guys i'm using Python with Tkinter, in this portion of code how to bind the key "Return" to the "siri" variable that is simply an image attached to the canvas?

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
from ctypes import windll
def click(*args):
    print("aaaaaaaaaaaaaa")
windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)
root = Tk()
root.title("Echeca")
root.geometry("400x400")
root.state("zoomed")
foto = (Image.open("bottone.png"))
resized_image= foto.resize((150,150))
new_image= ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_image)
sfondo = PhotoImage(file="robotagnocca.png")
canvas = Canvas(root)
sfondino = canvas.create_image(960,450, image=sfondo)
siri = canvas.create_image(669.5,280, image=new_image)
canvas.create_text(200,130, text="Login",fill="green",font=("times",20,"bold"))
canvas.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=True)
canvas.tag_bind(sfondino, "<Button-1>", click)
mainloop()
```

With `"<Button-1>"` works but if i use `"<Return">` or `"<Escape>"` just like the normal .bind function it doesn't work... How to bind Return or Escape? Thanks!!

Comment: Why would you need to bind 'Return' or 'Escape' to images? Why not just bind it to the canvas itself? or the root window

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria Because i want to use the image as a button in this way i have a custom button, and for simplicity i bind the "Return" key to activate the button more quickly compared to move the mouse and click. So is possible to bind the Return key to the image? Thanks

Comment: What would be the difference between normally binding 'Return' to the canvas or the window and being _able_ to bind it to the image? Both _would_ work the same way right

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria please could you explain me how to bind "Return" to the canvas or the window as you said? I'm trying but i can't do it, i updated my question with the full code

Comment: Something as simple as `root.bind_all('<Return>',click)`, but before you do, read the difference between `bind` and `bind_all` and use wisely